# Using Python Ctypes for ssdeep's fuzzy.dll but receive error

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to use Python and ctypes to use the `fuzzy.dll` from ssdeep. So far everything I have tried fails with an access violation error. Here is what I do after changing to the proper directory which contains the `fuzzy.dll` and `fuzzy.def` files:

```
>>> import os,sys
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> fn = create_string_buffer(os.path.abspath("fuzzy.def"))
>>> fuzz = windll.fuzzy
>>> chash = c_char_p(512)
>>> hstat = fuzz.fuzzy_hash_filename(fn,chash)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000200
>>>
```

From what I understand, I have passed the proper `c_types`.  From `fuzzy.h`:

```
extern int fuzzy_hash_filename(char * filename, char * result)
```

I just cannot get past that access violation.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You should not use `windll.fuzzy`, but `cdll.fuzzy` -- from [ctypes documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries):

   > cdll loads libraries which export functions using the standard cdecl calling convention, while windll libraries call functions using the stdcall calling convention.
2. For return value (`chash`), you should declare a buffer rather than creating a pointer to `0x0000200` (=512) -- this is where the access violation comes from. Use `create_string_buffer('\000' * 512)` instead.

So your example should look like this:

```
>>> import os, sys
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> fn = create_string_buffer(os.path.abspath("fuzzy.def"))
>>> fuzz = cdll.fuzzy
>>> chash = create_string_buffer('\000' * 512)
>>> hstat = fuzz.fuzzy_hash_filename(fn,chash)
>>> print hstat
0 # == success
```